# Is there a list of rules?

Tags: discussion

Is there a single list of rules governing Stack Exchange sites (and if so, whre is it?)? More specifically, I'm interested in hard rules that are automatically enforced by the machine, or well-delimited rules that moderators are expected to follow? This is inspired by having seen questions that are notated (under review) "This question is too old to migrate" -- which suggests a rule. I also understand that there is a limit on the number of custom reasons a Beta site can have for closing questions. I basically am interested in rules embodied in the code, but extend that to rules that moderators have to enforce, in case it's too hard to write code to do it automatically. I am totally *not* asking about rules defining good and bad questions.

Comment: I don't think there is anything more specific than http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=frequent

Comment: @zondo actually [the main faq index](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) would be a better starting point.

Comment: My take is that there isn't any single list for that. Every meta question I had, had to be answered by digging through dozens of meta stuff, which sometimes even shuttles me between MSO and MSE.

Comment: Apparently my question should have been closed because it is completely unclear. The linked question does *not* answer the question, though from that, I can infer that the answer is "no".

Comment: Maybe more relevant:  [The Complete Stack Exchange Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/195817).